# Connect Codeigniter to ODBC that uses Windows Authentication

Tags: codeigniter, odbc, windows-authentication

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to connect to MS SQL through an ODBC that uses Windows Authentication. I have tested and verified all of the rest of the code by using a standard ODBC connection that requires a user/pass. Below are the settings that work with that ODBC and the settings I have tried on the Windows Authentication ODBC.

Working database.php settings -standard user/pass connection

```
    $active_group = 'jf2';
    $active_record = TRUE;
    $db['jf']['hostname'] = 'system DSN name';
    $db['jf']['username'] = 'db_user';
    $db['jf']['password'] = 'db_pass';
    $db['jf']['database'] = 'db_name';
    $db['jf']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
    $db['jf']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['jf']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['jf']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['jf']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['jf']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['jf']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['jf']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['jf']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['jf']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['jf']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

non-working database.php settings - Windows Auth attempt

```
    $active_group = 'jf1';
    $active_record = TRUE;

    $db['jf1']['hostname'] = 'system DSN name';                
    $db['jf1']['username'] = '';
    $db['jf1']['password'] = '';
    $db['jf1']['database'] = 'db_name';
    $db['jf1']['dbdriver'] = 'odbc';
    $db['jf1']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['jf1']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['jf1']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['jf1']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['jf1']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['jf1']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['jf1']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['jf1']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['jf1']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['jf1']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Specifically, I am unsure what will go into the user/pass fields. The error is below:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter_2.1.2\boss_table\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 124

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to add Trusted_Connection = TRUE to any of the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db['jf1']['hostname'] = 'system DSN name';                
$db['jf']['username'] = '';
$db['jf']['password'] = '';
$db['jf1']['database'] = 'db_name';
```

You are setting the username and password key on the `jf` database group instead of on the `jf1` group.

```
$db['jf1']['hostname'] = 'system DSN name';                
$db['jf1']['username'] = 'insert_username';
$db['jf1']['password'] = 'insert_password';
$db['jf1']['database'] = 'db_name';
```

Comment: Hi Geert, Thanks for the reply. The 'jf' for username and password was a typo. This has been corrected in my original question and I am still unable to connect. I have tried removing the username and password requirements for this database group since these are supplied by the authentication but this has not worked either. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you enable remote access to the DB?

Comment: Yes. I have also tested the connection using BI tools without any problem.